# Homeomorphism between open sets in $\mathbb{R}$ induces bijection between open intervals?

Tags: real-analysis

Assume that $Q\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ and $K\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ are locally compact Hausdorff open susbets of real line. 
It is well known that open set in $\mathbb{R}$ is a countably union of disjoint open intervals. 
Let 
$$Q = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty I_n \text{ and } K = \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty J_k$$
where $\{ I_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ and $\{ J_k \}_{k=1}^\infty$ are sequences of mutually disjoint open intervals.

> **Question**: If there is a homeomorphism $\phi:Q\to K,$ then can we say that there is a bijection between $I_n$ and $J_k?$

I think the bijection should exist but I do not know how to prove it.

Comment: There is a bijection between any two open intervals of $\mathbb{R}$. Do you mean a bijection induced by $\phi$? Edit : sorry, you already said it in the title.

Answer (score 2):

$\phi$ induces a homeomorphism from $I_n$ to its image $\phi(I_n)$. Since $I_n$ is connected, we have $\phi(I_n)\subseteq J_k$ for some $k$.

Note that you cannot cover $J_k$ by multiple disjoint open intervals. Hence $\phi(I_n)=J_k$. Since this is a homeomorphism, it is in fact a bijection.

Edit : I assumed that $I_n$ are pairwise disjoint (also $J_k$ are pairwise disjoint). Otherwise $\phi$ does not induce a bijection. Consider $(0,2)\cup (1,3) = (0,3)$ and take the identity map on $(0,3)$. Then this does not induce a bijection from $(0,2)$ to $(0,3)$.